# How to do a radial translation without scaling

Tags: modeling

[image: How to I translate this to fit the edge of the tree. If I use scale it changes the size of the objects.]

How do I translate this radially without using scale. When I use scale it effects the size.

Comment: if these meshes (loose parts) belong to one object then it is not possible to do what you think. It would be better to work with arrays or separate them , do the translation and then rejoin them !

Comment: Could you share your blend file so that we can take a look at it? You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy pasting the generated url here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I assumed this to be true. Ill use an array. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: if they are separate objects you can use the Manipulate Center Points option and scale all your objects (make sure that they all have their origin point to geometry. Otherwise you could use the Dupliframes technique and increase the bezier circle.